# How to use Qualtrics functions (e.g., loop and merge) for a simple experiment with randomized presentation of conditions?

Tags: qualtrics

I am sitting up a simple experiment where there will be 5 conditions that participants will be presented in randomized order (call them A, B, C, D, and E. The researcher will show all conditions to every participant based on a randomization table (so each participant will not see the same condition first, second etc - example, participant 1 may see conditions in this order: A, E, C, B, D). They will then answer the exact same series of questions about every condition.

I want to know how to use Qualtric’s loop and merge feature for this. Would it be a loop and merge based off a question, something like, “researcher, which condition is the participant seeing now?” And the researcher selects that condition, the participant cycles through the corresponding questions, but then it needs to loop back to the same question at the beginning where the researcher selects which condition the participant is seeing next? They need to cycle through questions for every condition.

I’ve read all the Qualtrics loop and merge documentation on this and basic functionality is known to me but I’m a coding and Qualtrics noob. I’m having trouble conceptually understanding how to set this up, as it is simple but doesn’t seem to match any of the examples given in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to base the loop & merge off a question.  Just set up 5 loops/rows (A, B, C, D, E) in your Loop & Merge setup and click the Randomize Loops checkbox at the bottom.

Update based on first comment below:
Basing the loop off a question won't help, because there is no way to force a specific order in the question it is based off.  You could ask the A through E question as the first question in the loop, then the remaining questions would be about that condition. However, the resulting data will be messy because the Loop data (1 through 5) could be associated with any of the conditions (A through E). You would have to 'decode' it based on the answer to the first question in the loop.

Comment: Thank your for your reply. I wanted to clarify that this is not a self-guided survey, a researcher will be showing prototype conditions to participants in a set order based on an (external from Qualtrics, printed) randomization order table (e.g., P1 sees: A, D, E, B, C; P2 sees C, A, B, E, A in that order, etc). Participants are not going through the survey themselves. So the moderator will need to be able to select which condition they are showing the participant every single time. So they will need to re-answer the question every single time. Does that make sense? Any advice appreciated!

Comment: I've updated the answer based on new requirements in the comment above

Comment: Thanks T. Gibbons for the update! I decided to go based on your original suggestion, do a loop and merge and click randomize loops. Do you happen to know how I can insert piqued text into the headings of questions so the researcher can clearly see what prototype condition they should be showing the participant for that question block so there is no confusion?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out! Thank you T. Gibbons! (I can't upvote because I'm new and don't have 15 reputation points yet, but otherwise I would!)